# activeadmin controller for storing data in another table rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have two models Session and Speaker. Here one Session may have many Speakers and one Speaker  may speak in many sessions, so I have used has_many relation, my models are looking like this

class Speaker < ActiveRecord::Base

```
has_many :session_speakers
has_many :sessions, :through => :session_speakers
```

end

class Session < ActiveRecord::Base

```
has_many :session_speakers
has_many :speakers, :through => :session_speakers
```

end

and the join table is

class SessionSpeaker < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :session
   belongs_to :speaker
end

the problem is when am selecting multiple speakers in session form speakers are getting stored in join table in console it is showing Unpermitted parameters: speaker_ids.

my session controller in activeadmin is like this

ActiveAdmin.register Session do
permit_params :speaker_ids, :title, :summary, :session_code, :session_type, :time_start_date, :time_start_time_hour, :time_start_time_minute, :time_end_date, :time_end_time_hour, :time_end_time_minute, :event_year_date, :event_year_time_hour, :event_year_time_minute

end

Please help me to solve this issue.
how can I make store speakers details into join table

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To declare that the value in params must be an array of permitted scalar values map the key to an empty array:

Try to use `speaker_ids: []`

```
ActiveAdmin.register Session do
  permit_params :title, :summary, :session_code, :session_type, :time_start_date, :time_start_time_hour, :time_start_time_minute, :time_end_date, :time_end_time_hour, :time_end_time_minute, :event_year_date, :event_year_time_hour, :event_year_time_minute, speaker_ids: []
end
```